# JodaTime - NoSuchMethodError: DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendFixedDecimal

Tags: java, jodatime, json-schema-validator

While executing below piece of code

```
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactory;

JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault();
```

I am getting below error.

```
]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendFixedDecimal(Lorg/joda/time/
DateTimeFieldType;I)Lorg/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
        at com.github.fge.jsonschema.format.common.DateTimeAttribute.<clinit>(DateTimeAttribute.java:56)
        at com.github.fge.jsonschema.library.format.CommonFormatAttributesDictionary.<clinit>(CommonFormatAttributesDictionary.java:52)
        at com.github.fge.jsonschema.library.format.DraftV3FormatAttributesDictionary.<clinit>(DraftV3FormatAttributesDictionary.java:47)
        at com.github.fge.jsonschema.library.DraftV3Library.<clinit>(DraftV3Library.java:32)
        at com.github.fge.jsonschema.cfg.ValidationConfigurationBuilder.<clinit>(ValidationConfigurationBuilder.java:63)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Used maven dependency is as below.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Can someone please help me out to figure out what could be wrong?

Comment: Looks like the JSON schema validator has an implicit dependency to joda-datetime. Can you post the output of `mvn dependency:tree` ?

Comment: here is dependency tree.

Comment: not allowing me to post complete tree.

Yes Bastian it has implicit depedency to joda.

[INFO] \- com.github.fge:json-schema-validator:jar:2.2.6:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO]    +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO]    +- com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:jar:6.2:compile
[INFO]    +- com.github.fge:json-schema-core:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.github.fge:uri-template:jar:0.9:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- com.github.fge:msg-simple:jar:1.1:compile
..........

Comment: I guess you need to switch to a different joda version - or file a bug for the schema validator which should declare all its dependencies in the pom.xml. You could post your dependency tree by editing the question and appending it.

Comment: Thanks Bastian,

but i am wondering how it is working in my stand alone java application but not with my web application.

Comment: (library author here) Maybe you use an old version of Joda Time which doesn't support this method. According to Joda Time javadoc, `.appendFixedDecimal()` appears in Joda Time 1.5.

Comment: Thanks for your time!!!

When i unzip my ear i see joda-time-2.3.jar in lib

Comment: Well, the ear is not the only thing to check here; depending on your servlet container, there are other elements prepended to an application's classpath before the ones of your app itself.

Comment: i am using weblogic 10. can you please be specific.

in some other thread i read i can not use Github directly, there its mentioned that one has to download a clone copy and some kind of setup.

can you please confirm having just maven dependency is good enough or not?

Comment: @fge,

can you please reply on https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator/issues/109 

issue looks related to this.

Comment: What, weblogic _again_? Gee... It also has problems with Guava...

Comment: OK, my hypothesis is that weblogic has a joda-time dependency "built in", which it will use in all webapps regardless of the fact that a given webapp may depend on another version of the same library; weblogic is already known to me to include an old version of Guava which brings conflicts in `Equivalence`. Maybe this is the same problem.

Comment: Thanks fge!!! your assumption is correct. It is resolved now.

Comment: Maybe your web container has joda on the classpath, and you web application inherits it